# count unique entry in a particular column between search pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, aix

Input File

```
Device Robot Drive       Robot                    Drive                Device      Second
Type     Num Index  Type DrNum Status  Comment    Name                 Path        Device Path
robot      0    -    TLD    -       -  -          -                    /dev/sg66
  drive    -    0 hcart2    3      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.006  /dev/nst17
  drive    -    1 hcart2    4      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.000  /dev/nst16
  drive    -    2 hcart2    5      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.001  /dev/nst15
  drive    -    3 hcart2    6      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.002  /dev/nst14
  drive    -    4 hcart2    2      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.007  /dev/nst13
  drive    -    5 hcart2    1      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.008  /dev/nst12
  drive    -    6 hcart2   12    DOWN  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.003  /dev/nst11
  drive    -    6 hcart2   12    DOWN  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.003  /dev/nst1
  drive    -    7 hcart2   10      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.004  /dev/nst10
  drive    -    7 hcart2   10      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.004  /dev/nst9
  drive    -    8 hcart2    9      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.005  /dev/nst5
  drive    -    8 hcart2    9      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.005  /dev/nst6
  drive    -    9 hcart2    8      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.009  /dev/nst4
  drive    -    9 hcart2    8    DOWN  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.009  /dev/nst2
  drive    -   10 hcart2    7      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.010  /dev/nst3
  drive    -   10 hcart2    7      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-TD5.010  /dev/nst0
robot      1    -    TLD    -       -  -          -                    /dev/sg55
  drive    -   11 hcart2    4      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-HH5.000  /dev/nst19
  drive    -   12 hcart2    2      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-HH5.001  /dev/nst18
  drive    -   13 hcart2    1      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-HH5.002  /dev/nst8
  drive    -   14 hcart2    3      UP  -          IBM.ULT3580-HH5.003  /dev/nst7
```

I want to find out or rather put in a variable that robot 0 has 11 drives(unique count of field 3) under it and robot 1 has 4

Need to ignore 1st 2 rows which i was doing through awk NR>2

There could be many robot's 0,1,2,3 So i need generic code I tried with awk but couldn't get a definite code.

Output

```
robot 0 : 11 
robot 1 : 4
```

and so on

Comment: Yes field 3 unique entries, which comes out 11 as 6,7,8,9,10 are redundant

Comment: could it happen that drive numbers go in arbitrary order, non sorted? like `drive 1 , drive 3, drive 7, drive 1`

Comment: yeah that's fine, i just need the count

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/robot/{ 
         if (r){ printf "%s : %d\n", r, c; c=0; delete a } 
         r = $1 OFS $2; 
     }
     /drive/ && !a[$3]++{ c++ }
     END{ printf "%s : %d\n", r, c }' file
```

- `r = $1 OFS $2` - *"robot"* name
- `delete a` - delete all the elements of the array `a`. (The following statement provides a portable but nonobvious way to clear out an array: `split("", array)`)
- `c++` - count unique *"drive"* numbers for a certain *"robot"*

---

The output:

```
robot 0 : 11
robot 1 : 4
```

Comment: I got an error in AIX. 

 Syntax Error The source line is 2.
 The error context is
                         if (r){ printf "%s : %d\n", r, c; c=0; delete a >>>  } <<<
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 2.
 Syntax Error The source line is 5.

Comment: Any response for AIX code? Linux it seems fine

Comment: @Sid, try this line `if (r){ printf("%s : %d\n", r, c); c=0; delete a; }` instead

Comment: Nope still this error,  `Syntax Error The source line is 2.
 The error context is
                         if (r){ printf("%s : %d\n", r, c); c=0; delete >>>  a} <<<
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line is 2.
 Syntax Error The source line is 3.
        awk: 0602-540 There is a missing } character`

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @Sid, share the link with a representative screenshot and give your `awk --version`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54AH2Y90rfkT1RGYWJKaEIxSjJnVUM2ZzdmZlEtRjVMNGJv

Comment: @Sid, I've also asked about `awk --version`

Comment: I am using your version only which works fine in Linux but gives me above error on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1=="robot" && $2 == "1" {x=NR+5} (NR<=x) {print}' test  | awk '{print $3}' | sed '/-/d' |wc -l | awk '{print "robot1:" " "  $0}'
```

robot1: 4

```
 awk 'NR >2 {print $0}' test  |sed -n '/robot/,/robot/{x;p;d;};x'| sed '/^$/d' | sed '/robot/d' | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq | wc -l | awk '{print "robot0:" " " $1}'
```

robot0: 11

Comment: As checked its working fine